# Problems trying to send email with Laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5, laravel-mail

I made an **API with Laravel** and it is registering the data correctly

Now I'm trying to get this to trigger registration confirmation emails, however these are not going

I'm using **Mailtrap** for the tests

In `.env` I put like this:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=291ac7fdcf52bb
MAIL_PASSWORD=610b2e5e9782d3
```

No `Http/Mail/DataManifestMail.php` tenho:

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class DataManifestMail extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    protected $inputs;

    public function __construct($inputs)
    {
        $this->inputs = $inputs;
    }

    public function build()
    {
        return $this->view('mails.data');
    }
}
```

In `views/mails/data.blade.php` I only have one warning message:

```
<h1>Test e-mail</h1>
```

Then in my `Http/Controller/ManifestationController.php` I put it like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Manifestation;
use App\Mail\DataManifestationMail;
use Mail;

class ManifestationController extends Controller
{
    private $manifestation;

    public function __construct(Manifestation $manifestation)
    {
        $this->manifestation = $manifestation;
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $nr = Manifestation::max('nrmanifestation');

        $this->manifestation->nrmanifestation = $nr + 1;  
        $this->manifestation->dspass = $request->dspass;
        $this->manifestation->eeemail = $request->eeemail;
        $this->manifestation->address = $request->address;
        $this->manifestation->name = $request->name;
        $this->manifestation->latitude = $request->latitude;
        $this->manifestation->longitude = $request->longitude;

        $this->manifestation->save();

        Mail::to('vazag@c1oramn.com')->send(new DataManifestationMail());

        return response()->json([
            'result' => 
                $this->manifestation->nrmanifestation
            ]);
    }    
}
```

I have reread the documentation and my code several times and have not found any errors

What can it be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be multiple reasons:

- configuration is cached (use `php artisan config:cache`)
- you used invalid mailtrap data (you should have log in `laravel.log` file)
- your server has somehow blocked `2525` port

Also looking at your code it seems you miss passing `$input` parameter to constructor. You have:

```
public function __construct($inputs)
```

but you run:

```
->send(new DataManifestationMail());
```

without passing any value

Comment: Yes I already left the configuration of the inputs ready, however I decided to test the sending before passing the parameters

Comment: And since this did not work, I'm first trying to figure this out

Comment: And as for the port I've already used for testing other APIs on that PC, plus I tested it with an email I use on a system that runs on the network and it also did not work, so I do not think I'm even calling `Mail::to`

Comment: @Mate Are you sure you are hitting this controller method at all?

Comment: Data is being saved to the database and the result returning to the app

Comment: I'm using Lubuntu, do I have to configure anything on the SO?

Comment: @Mate Have you run `php artisan queue:work` command? It seems your mail is send in queue, so you should start worker to start processing emails (and probably e-mail will be delivered or you will get error in `laravel.log`)

Comment: `[2017-12-21 15:08:04] local.ERROR: Swift_TransportException: Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "291ac7fdcf52bb" using 3 possible authenticators in /var/www/html/apiTeste/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/Esmtp/AuthHandler.php:181`

Comment: I saw that this ID was the previous one in mailtrap so I cleared the cache and now it works, thanks

Comment: u now how can I change the subject?

Comment: @Mate Please ask another question if you have problem with something else